# Select a subpart of a csv according to another csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, sorting

I have a csv which I want to sort the rows according to the columns of another csv.

More precisely, I have a dataframe X whose rows are indexed with a specific column by pandas in the order of increasing integers (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) and each of the N rows also has another column containing an integer (also in increasing order 315, 378, 415, ...). Now I have a csv Y with several columns and arranged in ascending order 0,1,... also. I want to select the subpart Y_sub of Y only for the integers present in the specific column of X 315, 378, 415, ... I tried this code :

```
X = pd.read_csv(X)
Y = pd.read_csv(Y)
Y_sub = Y.loc[Y.index.isin(X.index)]
```

But this gives me the first N rows of Y.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, this is how you can do it:

```
specific_X_column = df_X["col_2"]
df_Y_subpart = df_Y.iloc[:, specific_X_column]
```

**Complete example:**

To be sure I understood you well, I'll rephrase your question:

- The dataframe "df_X" has a column that contains integers.
- These integers correspond to indexes of columns in an other dataframe named "df_Y"
- We want to select only these columns in "df_Y"

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframes "df_X"
data_X = [["A", 0], ["B", 3], ["C", 5]]
columns_X = ["col_1", "col_2"]
df_X = pd.DataFrame(data_X, columns=columns_X)
print(df_X)
print()

# Create dataframes "df_Y"
data_Y = [[0,1,2,3,4,5], [0.0, 10,20,30,40,50]]
columns_Y = ["col_0", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4", "col_5"]
df_Y = pd.DataFrame(data_Y, columns=columns_Y)
print(df_Y)
print()

# Select the column in "df_X" that contains the integers (indexes of columns in "df_Y")
specific_X_column = df_X["col_2"]

# Select the columns needed in "df_Y"
df_Y_subpart = df_Y.iloc[:, specific_X_column]
print(df_Y_subpart)
```

Output:

```
  col_1  col_2
0     A      0
1     B      3
2     C      5

   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
0    0.0      1      2      3      4      5
1    0.0     10     20     30     40     50

   col_0  col_3  col_5
0    0.0      3      5
1    0.0     30     50
```